# Java script button with permission set

Tags: javascript, custom

Only user with Manage Account permission set can use this button, I have created this button but how can I add permission set with error message for other user. Could Anyone help me about this . Thanks in advance

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")} 

var add = new sforce.SObject("Address"); 

add.Id = "{!Address.Id}"; 

add.Integration= true; 

sforce.connection.update([add]); 

window.location.reload(); 



var result = sforce.connection.query( SELECT PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE 
PermissionSet.Name = 'Manage PS Accounts']); 

var psAssignment = result.getArray("records"); 
if(psAssignment.length === 0) 
{ 
alert('You don't have access to this functionality.'); 
}
```

Comment: whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: You need to write the redirection and update inside else part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to go through all this work. Just create a [custom permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_perms_overview.htm&type=0), then access it via [$Permission](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_permission.htm):

```
if({!$Permission.Manage_Accounts}) {
    var record = new sforce.SObject("Address");
    record.Id = "{!Address.Id}";
    record.Integration = true;
    var results = sforce.connection.update([record]);
    // Consider checking results to ensure success or show error
    if(!results[0].getBoolean("success")) {
        alert("Error: "+results[0].errors[0].message);
    }
    window.location.reload();
} else {
    alert("You don't have access to this feature.");
}
```

I suspect that your object name and fields may not be correct; if they are custom, make sure you include the `__c`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked and learned new things today. Appreciate it.