# How to hide a button for sales manager profile in vf page?

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

**How to hide this button for sales manager profile in vf page?pls help!!**

```
<apex:commandButton 
    rendered="{!Order__c.Status_for_Eng__c!='Credit Check' || Order__c.Approved_for_credit_check__c==true}" 
    id="toggleBtn" 
    value="Send to ADS" 
    onclick="openModal(); return false;"
/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Onclick javascript button - how to enable and disable based on profiles](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219535/onclick-javascript-button-how-to-enable-and-disable-based-on-profiles)

Comment: It doesn't work, I just need to add a condition like $profile.name to the code I have posted but not able to figure out how.

Comment: please update your post with what exactly you are doing, and what error and behavior you are experiencing. "Not working" is not a problem description, and we can't help you with vague information. Make sure you properly format your code as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<apex:commandButton rendered="{!AND((Order__c.Status_for_Eng__c!='Credit Check' || Order__c.Approved_for_credit_check__c==true),( **$Profile.Name != 'Sales Manager'**))}" id="toggleBtn" value="Send to ADS" onclick="openModal(); return false;"/>